# unstandardized coefficients where mean-centered X variables have +/- values from 0

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-estimating-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to interpret regression coefficients for a variable with takes positive and negative values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25094/how-to-interpret-regression-coefficients-for-a-variable-with-takes-positive-and)

I'm performing negative binomial regression and one of my centered-mean X variables (with 200 observations) ranges between -0.2 and +0.2 around the 0.

Do regression coefficients only account for a positive increase from 0 on its effect on the dependent, or can/do/how they account for a negative shift from zero? How should I interpret my unstandardized B? Its value is negative.

FYI.
I'm testing to see if the increase in violence is influenced by a positive or negative change in vegetation cover (mean centered).

Comment: it is, but I don't think I explained my question properly so I posted a revised edition.

Comment: You can edit your question rather than re-posting. See the FAQ

Comment: As suggested by @Macro, you can edit your earlier question or add clarification as comments if you want to add some more details.